# How to close all orders on last bar in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, trading

When I simulate strategies, I sometimes can not estimate profitability automatically, because on last bar strategy contains open trades.

I can of course calculate such unclosed strategy profit manually. However, it looks better idea to close strategy on last bar automatically when I debugging it.

I don't want to set `process_orders_on_closed` to still have realistic result. I just need to initiate `close_all` on penultimate bar, so on last bar it will close the order with previous bar close price.

Is there a way to do that with Pine Script, or I need more serious programming environment than Pine Script for such customization?

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue:
I solved it like this as barstate.islast won't close it at end as it will wait till the next bar which will never appear until it is live marked and in that case you have to use barstate.islastconfimedhistory.

For this problem, use it like this.
Logic: time in script from current time difference is used to identify last to last trading day, the strategy can close on last day.

`//For PineScript v5.0 isLastTradingDay = ((timenow-time)<300000000)                                                     if (isLastTradinDay)                                                                              strategy.closeAll("Exit at end of script")`

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use data which is known before the last bar, and that is the current time, regardless of other variables, it can be retrieved with 'timenow'.

This solution works on all timeframes. First check in the current timeframe how many milliseconds there are. Next add a condition to exit if the time is within the last bar time.

```
bar_ms = timeframe.in_seconds() * 1000
if timenow - time_close(timeframe.period) < bar_ms
    strategy.close_all('exit')
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post